# WinForms/C#: Implementing long scrollable list of images blows up memory

Tags: c#

I try to load jpg-images as a long list of picture boxes into a table layout panel. The list of the images should be scrollable smoothly, i.e. without flickering or visible blurring or dithering. There are around 300 images, each with a size of around 150kb (600px x 850px).

The problem is that when loading the images into the panel, the memory (RAM) is much more blown up that it should be (considered the size of the images files). If the list is loaded, around 500Mb are blocked in memory, but the images should need around 300 x 150kb = 45MB.

It does not matter if I load the image into the picturebox directly or as MemoryStream: The result concerning the memory load is the same.

So, something is blowing up my memory-load, to an extent of more than 10 times as much as the image files would need.

The question is: How can I get the memory load under around 100Mb without changing image quality or image size. Does anyone have a good idea?

Thank you very much in advance

rockie

Comment: I suggest you to load the images dynamically. At a given time, user may not be viewing all the images. Load only the images that are in the user view

Comment: This looks like trying to put a 600 horse power engine into a small Fiat Punto :)

Comment: The user wants to be able to scroll without loss of image quality. If I load a first part of the images and load the second part if the user begins to scroll, then the display of the images is very poor. I tried to load a second part of the images in a backgroundworker process - but here also I have the problem of poor display of the images!

Comment: Would it not be better to have up/down buttons for the scrolling and load the pictures dynamically? As danishgoel have answered there is no way to get this done without the high memory usage.. Also WinForms are not the best to use for smooth scrolling of large images etc

Comment: keep us posted on your progress. Also did my answer below help ? If it solved your problem please mark it as accepted answer. If not you can further ask for help.

Comment: @rockie667 So how's the progress on this, did the CompressibleImage class work for your purposes? Do not hesitate to ask for further help if needed.

Comment: @danishgoel: The performance became a lot better (much less memory load) and the display during scrolling is considerably good. But unfortunately a new problem arised. When I scroll down, the rest of the list after the first quarter is blank. Very strange: if I scroll down until line 70 (of around 325) or so, all the images are visible, but from line 71 on none of the pictureboxes and labels is painted. If I resize the form (for example minimize and then maximize the window), the next 70 rows are displayed. Do you have any idea? But anyway: thanks so much for your help so far!!! :)

Comment: @rockie667 It seems as if the EventHandler responsible for adding more images to the subsequent rows and removing the earlier ones is being called on resize of the form. Are the 70 rows you say being displayed loaded initially ? this would explain the problem. For more complete help, on new issues I would suggest either you update the question here with new information and related code, or start a new one and put the link to it in the comment here so I can track it there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The size of your JPG images in memory is the memory used by uncompressed images.

```
MemorySize = w * h * (number of images) * (3 or 4 bytes)
             -> w, h is in pixels
```

3 bytes or 24 bits for images without transparency and 4 Bytes for images with transparency. It is 8bits per channel (Red, Green, Blue, Transparency) per pixel.

So in your case this is:

```
MemorySize = 600 * 850 * 300 * 3 = 459000000 bytes ~ 440 MB
```

Only solution to keep memory usage under 100MB would be to only load the first 70 Images and load the further needed images once a user scrolls down further, while at the same time removing images from top.

Say if there are n images in each your row and k rows are visible.
It would be better to say initially load the first `n * (k+2)` images. Then as the user scrolls below a row, remove the images in the now invisible row and load the next row/s images. For this add some kind of EventHandler to scroll event.

**Update**
Searching on Google for Compressed in memory Bitmap, i found this:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/CompressibleImage.aspx

Check it out, it can save time in loading images from disk, you are then only decompressing them on run-time thus saving disk access time.

I am right now trying this class in a sample project and would update the answer with results.

**Update 2**

I have tested the CompressibleImage Class and its working fine.
But as it re-compresses your image, which is already JPEG compressed it can cause some loss of quality.
For that I have added an additional constructor to the class which stores the raw file bytes directly in the compressed stream variable of the class. So add the Following Constructor and it should work without any loss of quality due to re-compression:

```
public CompressibleImage(string fileName, bool alreadyCompressed){
    if (alreadyCompressed)
        this.stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName));
    else
        this.decompressed = Image.FromFile(fileName);
}
```

You Can then use the class as follows:

```
// to load image in compressed format, where filename points to a JPG
// and the second argument as true tells that the image is already compressed
CompressibleImage ci = new CompressibleImage(filename, true);

// to display in a PictureBox
pictureBox1.Image = ci.GetDecompressedImage();

// to free image memory once out of view
pictureBox1.Image = null;
ci.ClearDecompressedImage();

// force Garbage Collector, do this after removing a whole row of images, 
// as by default GC is not called immediately but only when needed, so
// this forces GC and reclaims memory from just freed images immediately
GC.Collect();
```

Give it a try and see if there is still loss of quality or stutter in scrolling

Comment: Thank you very much for clear calculation of memory usage. Unfortunately when loading another images in a backgroundworkerproces during user is scrolling, the display of the images is rather poor! This in my case is not acceptable!

Comment: Look at the updates in my answer, they link to a CompressibleImage class and some further code examples. Can you try them out and inform us of your results.

Comment: danishgoel, you are so great! Thanks a thousand times for your endless efforts! I will try it out at once and of course tell you about results... Thank you so much!